# Extend hfill to the border of the cell

Tags: tables, fill

I am using `\hrulefill\hfill` to create horizontal lines. The problem is that these lines do not touch the border of the cell. How can I make them touch the vertical border lines of the cell?

An ASCII art example:

Now I get this

```
| Class 1 | Class 2 |
|  ---------------  |
```

I would like to get this

```
| Class 1 | Class 2 |
|-------------------|
```

Solutions that use `tabular` instead of alternative environments like `tabularx` are preferred.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|>{\centering}p{2em}|>{\centering}p{2em}|>{\centering}p{2em}|>{\centering}p{2em}|}
\hline 
 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Class 1} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Class 2}\tabularnewline
\hline 
A & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\hrulefill\hfill}\tabularnewline
\hline 
B &  & \hrulefill\hfill & \hrulefill\hfill & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I removed all the `\hfill` in most cases `\hrullefill\hfill` would halve the length of the line, with the left half of the space being filled by the rule, and the right half being filled by the hfill, in tables space at the end of the cell is removed so the `\hfill` does nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to account for `\tabcolsep` in one of various ways:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|>{\centering}p{2em}|>{\centering}p{2em}|>{\centering}p{2em}|>{\centering}p{2em}|}
\hline 
 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Class 1} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Class 2}\tabularnewline
\hline 
A & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\hrulefill\hfill}\tabularnewline
\hline 
B &  & \hrulefill\hfill & \hrulefill\hfill & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{|c|>{\centering}p{2em}|>{\centering}p{2em}|>{\centering}p{2em}|>{\centering}p{2em}|}
\hline 
 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Class 1} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Class 2}\tabularnewline
\hline 
A & \multicolumn{4}{@{}c@{}|}{\hrulefill}\tabularnewline
\hline 
B &  & \multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{}|}{\hrulefill}& 
\multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{}|}{\hrulefill} & \tabularnewline
\hline
1&2&3&4\tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}

\bigskip



{\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabular}{|c|>{\centering}p{2em}|>{\centering}p{2em}|>{\centering}p{2em}|>{\centering}p{2em}|}
\hline 
 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Class 1} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Class 2}\tabularnewline
\hline 
A & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\hrulefill}\tabularnewline
\hline 
B &  & \hrulefill & \hrulefill & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{|c|>{\centering}p{2em}|>{\centering}p{2em}|>{\centering}p{2em}|>{\centering}p{2em}|}
\hline 
 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Class 1} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Class 2}\tabularnewline
\hline 
A & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\mbox{}\kern-\tabcolsep\hrulefill\kern-\tabcolsep}\tabularnewline
\hline 
B &  &\mbox{}\kern-\tabcolsep\hrulefill\kern-\tabcolsep &
 \mbox{}\kern-\tabcolsep\hrulefill\kern-\tabcolsep & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}




\end{document}
```

Comment: I used the fourth solution but modified to read, for instance, `\kern-3\tabcolsep` instead of `\kern-\tabcolsep` because  in my document I have more merged columns, not just two as in this example.

Comment: @gioele no you should only require one `\tabcolsep` at each end, no matter how many columns you span